# Posting Data using HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, servlets, http-post, httpconnection

I need to post data to server using HttpURLConnection. Data contains Thai character as well. Server which accept post request accept encoding UTF-8 and TIS-620 both. When I directly post data from rest client it works fine, but when I send same request from java code it is not working properly, I mean when I send UTF-8 format data it gives parse exception and when I use TIS-620 instead thai text in server I am getting some speial character square etc.( I do not any have handle on server which accept data )

I am setting same header property for HttpURLConnection which I set for rest client in browser.Please let me know what could be going wrong here

As per my requirement I have to write this code in servlet , and servlet is called from browser AJAX call. In JQUERY AJAX call while sending data I am setting

```
beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader( "Content-type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8" );
                },
```

I changed UTF-8 to TIS-620 All places but no luck

Some finding :

when I set 
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8"); 
and Print `connection.getContentType()` it is only printing *application/json*

If I send only English text it works fine. I am giving servlet code below which accept post request and POST it to server

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.err.println("************** POST CALLED **************");

        //PRINT SERVLET REQUEST PROPERTY
        System.err.println("CharacterEncoding : "+ request.getCharacterEncoding());
        System.err.println("ContentType : "+request.getContentType());

        //SEND GET REQUEST AND FETCH XCSRF TOKEN
        String dummyServiceUrl = "GET_LOT_SRV/get_lot";
        String xcsrfToken = null;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        String requestURL = httpPrefix + hostName + semiColon + portNumber + forwardSlash + dummyServiceUrl;
        List<String> cookies = null;
        try {
            URL gatewayServiceUrl = new URL(requestURL);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) gatewayServiceUrl.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", this.getBasicAuth());
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
            connection.setRequestProperty("x-csrf-token", "fetch");
            connection.connect();
            if (HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK == connection.getResponseCode()) {
                //ON SUCCESS GET XCSRF TOKEN AND IN SAME SESSION POST DATA 
                requestURL = httpPrefix + hostName + semiColon + portNumber + forwardSlash + request.getQueryString();
                gatewayServiceUrl = new URL(requestURL);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) gatewayServiceUrl.openConnection();

                //SET CONNECTION PROPERTY
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                xcsrfToken = connection.getHeaderField("x-csrf-token");
                cookies = connection.getHeaderFields().get("set-cookie");
                // SET COOKIES
                for (String cookie : cookies) {
                    String tmp = cookie.split(";", 2)[0];
                    connection.addRequestProperty("Cookie", tmp);
                }
                //SET HEADERS
                connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", this.getBasicAuth());
                connection.setRequestProperty("x-csrf-token", xcsrfToken);
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                connection.setRequestProperty("DataServiceVersion", "2.0");
                connection.setRequestProperty("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8"); 

                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setUseCaches(false);

                //SET USERS INPUT DATA TO OUTPUT STREAM
                String payload = this.getDataFromStreamPost(request.getInputStream());
                DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
                dataOutputStream.write(payload.getBytes());
                dataOutputStream.flush();
                dataOutputStream.close();

                //POST DATA AND CHECK RESPONSE
                connection.connect();
                response.setStatus(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED);
                response.setContentType("application/json; charset=TIS-620");
                response.getWriter().println(this.getDataFromStream(connection.getInputStream()));

            } else {
                System.err.println("XCSRF GET FAILURE "+connection.getResponseCode());
                response.setStatus(connection.getResponseCode());
                response.setContentType("application/json; charset=TIS-620");
                response.getWriter().println(this.getDataFromStream(connection.getInputStream()));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("EXCEPTION OCCURED IN POST : "+e.getMessage());
            response.setStatus(connection.getResponseCode());
            response.setContentType("application/json; charset=TIS-620");
            response.getWriter().println(this.getDataFromStream(connection.getErrorStream()));
        }
    }
        private String getBasicAuth() {
        String userpass = userName + ":" + password;
        return "Basic "
                + javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(userpass
                        .getBytes());
    }

    private String getDataFromStream(InputStream stream) throws IOException {
        StringBuffer dataBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        BufferedReader inStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                stream));
        String data = "";

        while ((data = inStream.readLine()) != null) {
            dataBuffer.append(data);
        }
        inStream.close();

        return dataBuffer.toString();
    }
    private String getDataFromStreamPost(InputStream stream) throws IOException {
        StringBuffer dataBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        BufferedReader inStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                stream,"UTF-8"));
        String data = "";

        while ((data = inStream.readLine()) != null) {
            dataBuffer.append(data);
        }
        inStream.close();

        return dataBuffer.toString();
    }
```